# Just create a column with all days of one month - with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I really try for more than 4 hour to do a simple task:
Create a column in a df with pandas that represent from day one to last day of the month.
For example:

```
index date
0     2018-08-01
1     2018-08-02
2     2018-08-03
...   ...
```

I'm giving up and do this in excel, save in csv to import again as a df in pandas...
thanks for any help!

Comment: Sure we can help. But why do you want this (purpose) and did you try something (so we can tell what you thought wrong). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The purpose is to create a column with each day of one month. Because I have several tables of data. Each table is a reference of one month. But no table has this column in the "date format". I need to append all tables together. If I dont have this date column in each table, after append will lost this temporal relation.

Comment: I try several commands. None work. The last one was: df['data']=pd.Timestamp(year=2018, month=8, day=1, freq=1)

Comment: This last one creates the same day in all rows. I thougth that "freq=1" will understand and do one day for each row.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, sure... I could not hold myself to write an answer to your question. When you say all the days in one month I directly think of: `how do we get the last day?` 
And the answer to that is using an offset (which is build-in in Pandas already).

Apart from that you are instersted for what in Pandas is called a [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html). There are numerous options to create a date range with for instance intervals and frequency (defaults to day). But to make it clear let us pass three variables:

1. start : our start date as a timeobject
2. end : our end date as a timeobject. Construct it with pandas offset Monthsend
3. frequency : day (this is optional but makes it clear that we want days)

*Note: The reason the offset helps is to easily pass the end date as the days of the month can vary.*

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

month = '2018-08'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(
        start = pd.Timestamp(month),                        
        end = pd.Timestamp(month) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0),  # <-- 2018-08-31 with MonthEnd
        freq = 'D'
    )
})
```

date_range is powerful, and if you want every hour you could do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(
        start = pd.Timestamp(month),
        end = pd.Timestamp(month) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) + pd.Timedelta(days=1),
        freq = 'H',     # <--- try '3h', '6h', '12h' if you want
        closed = 'left'
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried and also works. A litle more complex to understand than the solution give by Alexander. But more powerful if need the hour. Both works!

Comment: There are many ways to do things in pandas. I think you should go for the most readable option always. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Create a daily datetime index using the start and end times from a period with monthly frequency.

```
month = '2018-08'
period = pd.Period(month, freq='M')
>>> pd.Series(
        pd.DatetimeIndex(
            start=period.start_time, 
            end=period.end_time, 
            freq='D')
    ).to_frame('date')
     date
0    2018-08-01
1    2018-08-02
2    2018-08-03
...
30   2018-08-31
```

Comment: yeah ofc... the Period. Don't forget a dataframe was asked for though :).

Comment: First I create a  string variable in the format 'year-month'. Second create a variable that is now a "date" with this function "Series", and tell this date is "M"- month. Third create a varaible (put a name = before) that indicate it is a "series" and also indicate it is From day 1 of month to last day of the same month. I Understant, try it! And works! Thanks!

Comment: df['data-series']=result - Now I append the "result" of this series to my df, as a new column called 'data-series'. Works ok!